# insert date from drop down list to the access database

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have drop down list called check in date. (in year,in date, in month).

```
<td>Check-in Date</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><select name="inmonth" id="inmonth">
<option value="-1">Month</option>
<option value="0">January</option>
<option value="1">February</option>
<option value="2">March</option>
<option value="3">April</option>
<option value="4">May</option>
<option value="5">June</option>
<option value="6">July</option>
<option value="7">August</option>
<option value="8">September</option>
<option value="9">October</option>
<option value="10">November</option>
<option value="11">December</option>
</select>
        &nbsp;
        <select name="indate" id="indate">
        <option value="-1">Date</option>
        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="2">3</option>
        <option value="3">4</option>
        <option value="4">5</option>
        <option value="5">6</option>
        <option value="6">7</option>
        <option value="7">8</option>
        <option value="8">9</option>
        <option value="9">10</option>
        <option value="10">11</option>
        <option value="11">12</option>
        <option value="12">13</option>
        <option value="13">14</option>
        <option value="14">15</option>
        <option value="15">16</option>
        <option value="16">17</option>
        <option value="17">18</option>
        <option value="18">19</option>
        <option value="19">20</option>
        <option value="20">21</option>
        <option value="21">22</option>
        <option value="22">23</option>
        <option value="23">24</option>
        <option value="24">25</option>
        <option value="25">26</option>
        <option value="26">27</option>
        <option value="27">28</option>
        <option value="28">29</option>
        <option value="29">30</option>
        <option value="30">31</option>
        </select>
&nbsp;
<select name="inyear" id="inyear">
<option value="0">Year</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2011">2016</option>
</select></td>
```

i want to convert inmonth,inyear, and indate as a short date first before insert it to the access database. what syntax should i use? btw, i'm using asp.

Comment: If you are using asp then you should tag it asp... I did it, I am sure that's what you meant by that..

Comment: umm, i used to wrong tag. i mean to say how to convert it in classic asp.

Answer (score 0):

I Assume you are getting the values of selected Dropdown Item in a Postback then,

See you can simply take the values selected validate them and after that Parse them as a Valid date.

You can use DateTime.Parse or DateTime.TryParse for that or simply pass values of each dropdown to DateTime constructor, then you can call the [DateTime.ToShortDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) to get the date as you want it to be before submitting it to database.

Answer (score 0):

This should take the input and convert it to a date like `2010-01-04` (`YYYY-MM-DD`):

```
Dim inmonth, indate, inyear, thedate

inmonth = CInt(Request.Form("inmonth")) + 1
indate  = CInt(Request.Form("indate"))  + 1
inyear  = Request.Form("inyear")

thedate = inyear & "-" & Right(CStr(inmonth + 100), 2) & "-" & Right(CStr(indate + 100), 2)

If NOT IsDate(thedate) Then
    Response.Write "Invalid date"
Else
    ' do something else ... '
End If
```

<sup>**Note:** The `Right(CStr(variable + 100), 2)` code snippet is for adding a leading zero.</sup>

Comment: hi, I tried to do like what you told me, but i got data type mismatch error for CInt.This is my current code  
  
`if request.form("submit") = "Submit" then`      
   
`dim inyear,indate,inmonth,theindate`    
   
`inmonth = CInt(request.form("inmonth")) + 1`   
`indate = CInt(request.form("indate")) + 1`    
`inyear = request.form("inyear")`    
   
`theindate = inyear & "-" & Right(CStr(inmonth + 100), 2) & "-" & Right(CStr(indate + 100), 2)`    
   
`SQL = "Insert into Reservation(Checkin_Date) values (#" & theindate &"#)"`     
    
`connection.execute SQL`

Comment: `CInt` isn't essential, so you can remove it if it's giving problems.